# OOM in docker container

Tags: docker

Our docker container is based on Alpine Linux. It is running fine on Ubuntu instance in Amazon ECS with memory limit 512Mb. When when we tried to run same Docker container on CentOS, it was crashing with Out of Memory error, until we gave it at least 1Gb of memory.

What could be a reason?

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this. We'd need to know how much memory each instance (CentOS and Ubuntu) are using _before_ running the container. We'd also need to see how the containers are running, versions of Docker on each instance, relevant commands, process outputs, etc. so we can try to replicate ourselves. If you are just looking for guesses then my best guess would be that the baseline memory usage of CentOS is greater than Ubuntu. Where the container usage may be static, it may be that container + base OS usage on CentOS pushes it over 512MB.

Comment: @AndyShinn thank you for your guess. Yes, I need guesses. So far we found that any Docker container is taking twice more memory on CentOS, than on Amazon instances or my local Windows machine.